# Laravel 5 - где размещать основную логику?

Tags: laravel, модель-данных

Переношу со своего самописа на laravel. Контроллер laravel, который отвечает за рефералов: вывод их данных, подсчет рефералов, подсчет первой линни, и т.п. - всего 5 методов.

Гуглеж дал знать, что в контроллере их размещать нежелательно. С этим я согласен, т.к. и у меня эти методы были вынесены в модель.

Но в laravel модель - это жесткая привязка к таблице, значит нужно использовать что-то другое.

Далее, пишут что надо создавать некоторые сервис провайдеры. Посмотрел что это такое - и никак не могу врубиться в эту логику. Не совсем понятно - зачем создавать интерфейсы, и кучу других лишних движений?

В итоге создал в app директорию models2 , в ней модель class Team . И в контроллере Team - получаю через

```
public function index(Team $team)
```

Можно ли так делать, и если нет то как правильно? Разве создавать интерфесы - правильное решение?

Answer (score 3):

Ну, на такой вопрос вряд ли уложиться в несколько листов, но я все равно попробую :)

Во первых, что такое [`сервисы` и `репозитории`](https://laravel.io/forum/05-11-2014-service-vs-repository), и что это нам даст:

Это освободит контроллеры и модели от некой бизнес-логики и позволит вам легко поддерживать код. То есть можно написать какой нибудь небольшой код и воткнуть его в метод, который можно будет многократно использовать.

Например, есть у нас 2 контроллера: `UsersController`, `DashboardController`

И есть 2 модели: `User`, `Post`

Представьте себе, что вам нужно вывести пользователей с их постами, предварительно отфильтровав, а потом добавив какую-нибудь ещё логику.

В таких случаях создается некий класс, назовём его `UserService`, И некий публичный  метод `getUsersAndPostsByAttr` Который будет возвращать пользователей с его постами.

```
namespace App\Http\Services; // Или куда-нибудь еще: App\Services может быть

use User,Post; // это модели

class UserService
{
    // Тут можно как угодно извращаться :)
    public function getUsersAndPostsByAttr($data)
    {
        // Какая-то логика
    }
}
```

И уже вызывать его в контроллерах UsersController , DashboardController

```
 new \ App\Http\Srvices\UserService()->gtUsersAndPostsByAttr([id,name,emial ...])
```

Тут у нас возник bug или код должен быть дополнен какой то логикой(Скрыть часть строки емайл а вместо дополнит многоточием (`aa@aaa.com => aaa@a...`)). И чтоб изменения были везде.

Тут нам придется это реализовать всего лишь в одном месте в сервисe. Это работает по принципу что если бы мы инициализировали переменную в начале файла присвоив ей значение и использовали бы его там где нам нужно, а не передавали значение во многих местах и потом вспоминали где мы эти значения писали․

А что касается интерфейсов можно [почитать тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.interfaces.php)

> Можно ли так делать, и если нет то как правильно?

Отвечаю:

Допустим есть роут типо `Route::get('user/{name}', 'ShowProfile@index');`,

и контроллер `ShowProfile` с вашим приведенным примером action

```
public function index(Team $team)
```

и `url` соответствующий вашему роутеру выглядит так `http://site.ru/user/Вася`, где name=Вася Вася-это строка, а не объект. А в актион `index(Team $team)` вы ожидаете значение по типу данного объекта, и у вас будет ошибка, поскольку Вася это строка а не объект.

**Один из вариантов как можно: **

Routing: `Route::get('user/{type}', 'HomeController@index');`

HomeController@index:

```
public function index($type) {
    $res = Team::where('type',$type)->firstOrFail();
    dd($res);
}

site.ru/team/friends
```

P.S:
Поскольку это из тех вопросов который порождает дискуссию и скорей всего меня станут упрекать в том, что сказал об одном, но не сказал о другом и так далее, а некоторые будут умничать ... То советую понять саму суть сказанного и уже в своей практике улучшить, дополнить её и поделиться с людьми которые будут нуждаться в этом совете.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Ваш пример отличается от того, что выдавал поисковик по этой теме. И самый понятный. Однако это практически то же самое что в итоге я и сделал, насмотревшись на примеры с интерфейсами, методом register и т.п. Поэтому и возник такой вопрос - что я не так делаю, и для чего они используются в примерах.

Comment: @Андрей  (Team $team) этот способ называют type hinting http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration